# How do use Guzzle 7 fully asynchronously with ReactPHP event loop without blocking for I/O?

Tags: php, asynchronous, reactphp

I have a DiscordPHP bot that I'm trying to download some web pages that require a cookie. It seems I need to use a curl handler with Guzzle because the ReactPHP http browser doesn't support cookies.

I've created this minimal script:

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlMultiHandler;
use GuzzleHttp\HandlerStack;
use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface;

include 'vendor/autoload.php';

$loop = \React\EventLoop\Loop::get();

$curl = new CurlMultiHandler;
$handler = HandlerStack::create($curl);
$client = new Client( [ /* 'cookies' => $cookieJar, */ 'handler' => $handler ] );

$promise = $client->getAsync('https://httpstat.us/200')
    ->then(
        function (ResponseInterface $res) {
            echo 'response: ' . $res->getStatusCode() . PHP_EOL;
        },
        function (\Exception $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage() . PHP_EOL;
        }
    );


$timer = $loop->addPeriodicTimer(0.5, function () use ($curl, $promise) {
    if ($promise->getState() === 'pending') {
    echo 'Tick ';
    $curl->tick();
    }
    echo 'Beat ';
});

$loop->run();
```

This exits immediately without the code adding the `addPeriodicTimer` to check *pending* and call `tick()` manually:

```bash
$ time php minimal.php
0.022u 0.010s 0:00.03 100.0%    0+0k 0+0io 67pf+0w
```

With the timer, it works as expected:

```bash
Tick Beat Tick Beat Tick Beat Tick Beat Tick Beat Tick Beat Tick response: 200
Beat Beat Beat ...
```

The idea to use a `tick()` came from this [73 comment closed thread on *github.com*](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/issues/1127#issuecomment-640171916).

There are some similar questions, but none of them seem to address this issue:

- [Asynchronous requests using proxy with Guzzle 7](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74994177), [Send asynchronous request without waiting the response using guzzle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44774990), [Use Guzzle pool instead of guzzle promises](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54999357), and [How to send multiple requests at once ReactPHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52389158) all use `wait()` which is a blocking call.
- [ReactPHP promises executed synchoniously](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32453834) uses a `sleep()` call and [Is ReactPHP truly asynchronous?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22502118) does a long `for` loop. Both are blocking the loop.
- [Guzzle vs ReactPHP vs Amphp for parallel requests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48530725) and [Guzzle and react Promise cause infine loop](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34851874) use older versions of Guzzle or deprecated code that doesn't work the same in Guzzle 7.

**How do I start a HTTP `GET` with a cookie jar and get the response in a ReactPHP event loop without using a blocking call such as `->wait()` or manually `tick()`ing curl's handler?**

Answer (score -2):

> the ReactPHP http browser doesn't support cookies.

Well, ReactPHP doesn't set cookies automatically, there's already a ticket discussing this topic: https://github.com/reactphp/http/issues/445, but you can still go the manual way and set HTTP cookie header.

It's also worth mentioning that using ReactPHP with Guzzle won't work as Guzzle will block ReactPHP's eventloop. This means you can send multiple requests, but can't do anything else asynchronously.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I’m aware of the ticket over cookies and the ability to set cookie headers manually (with much effort and code). However, using a url handler and manually ticking curl, there is zero blocking. My example minimal code demonstrates this. So this answer does answer the question and is a regression from what I have in the question.

Comment: Url handler should have been curl handler

Comment: could you comment on my points? Thank you